1.5" galvanized vent pipe as a fall arresting anchor
I am working on a roof design requirements. I would like to have a safety anchor other than  (or in addition to) the brick chimney. If a regular drain plumbing vent pipe used would be PVC, could that be replaced with galvanized steel and supported more firmly against the structural skeleton of the house so that, with a proper attachment, can be used as a safety anchor for harnesses when working on the roof?

No one is going to validate your homemade fall arresting equipment. That would be foolish. It would be foolish of you to accept such an answer. For one thing we don't know the specifics of what "more firmly" and "proper attachment" mean. Those are critical aspects of the thing, which may be called upon to handle 200 lbs. or more at 10 g's or more.

If you want roof anchors for personnel fall safety, buy and install roof anchors that are designed for the exact job.
They are made, they are common, and they can be permanently installed for use when needed.

Yes, fall protection is not something to kludge together. Fall forces are much larger than one imagines.
